# Barplot averages with strings as x axis

Tags: r, plot

so i'm having some trouble creating a barplot with strings as the x axis and the height as its averages.

so say i have a column called `fruits = c("strawberry", "apple", "strawberry", "banana", "apple"....)`

and a corresponding column with its `count = c(2, 3, 4, 2,...)`

I've tried doing

```
barplot(as.numeric(fruits$amount), names.arg = fruits$type)
```

but that seems gives a bar for every single occurrence of the fruit. so I'm getting 100+ bars even though i have only around 10 types of fruit.

I've also tried converting it to a table before hand and plotting that but that also doesn't work.

```
test <- table(as.numeric(fruits$amount), row.names = fruits$type)
barplot(test)
```

I'm new to R so I aplogize if this is a obvious fix/dumb question. Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
fruits <- data.frame(amount=c(2,3,5,1,7), type=c("Strawberry",
                                  "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Orange"))

b <- barplot(as.numeric(fruits$amount), names.arg = fruits$type,
        horiz = T, las=1, xlim=c(0,10), col="steelblue")

abline(v=mean(fruits$amount), col="red", lwd=2)
axis(1,mean(fruits$amount), col.axis ="red")
text(y = b, x = fruits$amount,
          pos = 4, cex = 2, col="darkblue")
```

The output is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
#DATA
df1 = data.frame(fruits = c("strawberry", "apple", "strawberry", "banana", "apple"), 
                 counts = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 4))

#Summarize
temp = aggregate(counts~fruits, df1, sum)

#Plot
barplot(temp[["counts"]], names.arg = temp[["fruits"]], las = 1, horiz = TRUE)
```